# Firebase Functions work in firebase deployment, but not locally

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This code does not return any data in localhost, but works well when deployed in firebase. Any suggestions? (tried with both 'firebase emulators:start' & 'npm run serve'). 
I should get a json object containing courses.
I tried with try/catch without any result:

- 'npm run server' ("npm run build && firebase serve --only functions")

> Error: Could not load the default credentials.  Error: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise 
>       rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a 
>       non-zero exit code. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error 
>       originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch 
>       block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

- 'firebase emulators:start' -> no error, but an empty json: {"courses":[]}

Link to code: https://github.com/angular-university/firebase-course/blob/1-firebase-finished/functions/src/index.ts

```
  import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
    import {db} from './init';
    import * as express from "express";
    const cors = require('cors');
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors({origin:true}));

    app.get('/courses', async (request, response) => {
        const snaps = await db.collection('courses').get();
        const courses:any[] = [];
        snaps.forEach(snap => courses.push(snap.data()));
        response.status(200).json({courses});
    });

    export const getCourses = functions.https.onRequest(app);

_____________________________________________________________________________

    init.ts

    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
    export const db = admin.firestore();
```

---

```
app.get('/courses', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const snaps = await db.collection('courses').get();
        const courses:any[] = [];
        snaps.forEach((snap: any) => courses.push(snap.data()));
        response.status(200).json({courses});
    } 
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err) 
    }
});
export const getCourses = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

---

Comment: What exactly are you doing and observing that's different than what you expect?  Please edit the question and be specific, so that anyone can reproduce your experience.

Comment: Sure, I put some more info. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The error message says "This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block".  Do you need a try/catch to find out if the database operation had some failure?

Comment: I have tried with  try/catch without any result. Is there another way to do try/catch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the rights credentials. It works on google cloud because there are environment variables that make this automatically.

---

You need to set locally this environment variable with the path to your credentials file. Try this in your terminal:

```
export FIREBASE_CONFIG="/user/path/to/credential.json"
```

[More info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_without_parameters)

---

Try following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). It gives good examples on how to do this.

Comment: The default service account that's provided by Cloud Functions (used when initializeApp is called with no parameters) should be sufficient for reading and writing Cloud Firestore, unless something strange has been done to that account that would revoke its access.

Comment: @DougStevenson but I though you need to set your own credentials when you are working locally

Comment: When using the local emulator, it should also have access to the default service account.  If you are just writing code to run outside the emulator, then you need to provide a service account.